# Escaping arrays using mysqli escape string

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I need to escape array's, I am using `array_map` with `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

I have multiple arrays like

```
$_post['countries'];
$_post['categories'];
.
.
```

How do I perform escaping on these arrays

I am doing this way

```
$countries=array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $_POST['countries']);
$categories=array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $_POST['categories']);
.
.
```

but it shows me error as `Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in`

also doing

```
$categories=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['categories']);
```

gives error as

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in
```

Please see and suggest a way or another better way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string is a function and how are you using this.

Comment: @Anant i tried this way first but it gives error as `Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in`

Comment: In mysqli almost aways ;) you need provide 2 arguments, first the connection and the 2nd the query etc

Comment: Use prepared statement insted of escaping

Comment: `array_map(function($arrayElement) use ($databaseConnection) { return mysqli_real_escape_string($databaseConnection, $arrayElement); }, $_POST['countries']);`.... but if you're already using MySQLi, then switch to using prepared statements with bind variables, and you won't need to escape these

Comment: @MarkBaker I am using prepared statements with bind variables, doing this for extra security.

Comment: @TallboY - If you think this is extra security, it isn't..... using bind variables does this for you ___automatically___; what you'll end up doing this manual escaping as well is "double escaping" which isn't good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of solutions here.

Considering you wanna stick to mysqli (PDO is now the recommanded way, but still a choice) and you want to keep using array_map on this context, you have to check the array_map prototype: http://php.net/array_map

> array array_map ( callable $callback , array $array1 [, array $... ] )

So:

1. *Using dynamic arguments of array_map*

   Note : this solution is a bad one, and was mistaken.

   Original answer : `$myArray = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $db, $myArray);`

   Updated answer : `$myArray = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $myArray, array_fill(0, count($myArray), $db));` and that's a bad idea with mysqli object.
2. **Using array callable**

   Because mysqli_real_escape_string is also a method of mysqli...
   `$myArray = array_map(array($db, 'real_escape_string'), $myArray);`
3. **Using closure**

   `$myArray = array_map(function($e) use($db) { return mysqli_escape_string($db, $e); }, $myArray);`

   or

   `$myArray = array_map(function($e) use($db) { return $db->real_escape_string($e); }, $myArray);`

Comment: what is `$db` database or connection?

Comment: Neither database nor connection. That's the mysqli object. It may handle a connection, maybe to a database... or not. That's just the base object for mysqli to be used. You had to create it, probably using a new mysqli.

Comment: getting error `Notice: Undefined variable: db` & `Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array`

Comment: Yes, you have to replace $db with your mysqli object, as I said earlier ;) mysqli always works with this object. You also have to replace $myArray by your array, obviously.

Comment: what mysqli object, I don't get this.

Comment: When you use mysqli. You perform some steps, one of the first is to create the mysqli object, which will be used to perform queries. For example, `$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'mypassword'); $db->query('show tables');`

Comment: I have this instead `$connection = mysqli_connect($host, $dbusername, $pass, $db)`

Comment: As the documentation states, mysqli_connect is in fact a deprecated alias of mysqli::__construct. So, the result of mysqli_connect IS the mysqli object you have to use :) In your case, so, the variable to use is $connection

Comment: result is `$connection` and i am using this but the error `Notice: Undefined variable: db & Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array`

Comment: So... In your case, considering your edits on main post, you should use: `$countries = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $connection, $_POST['countries']);` am I right ? Think about the PHP fondamentals, too : is $_POST['countries'] always exist ? Is it always an array ?

Comment: yes I have done like this only, and $_POST['countries'] always exist and is array

Comment: the error is `Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array`

Comment: Yes, right, I'll update the answer. Don't use first solution, either 2nd or 3rd.

Comment: array (size=2)
  0 => string '5' (length=1)
  1 => string '8' (length=1)

Comment: Answer is now updated. First solution is generally fine, but not in such a case.

Comment: ok,out of 2nd and 3rd which is faster?

Comment: 2nd one is probably the most appropriate. 3rd is generic and rich, but closures should not be used unless necessary.

Comment: I am using second one as I have lot of escaping to be done, Also thinking to just use prepaid statements as @MarkBaker has suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap `mysqli_real_escape_string()` call with an anonymous function to use within `array_map()` like this:

```
// $connection_object is a mysqli object declared somewhere above

$countries = array_map(function($item) use($connection_object) {
  return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection_object, $item);
}, $_POST['countries']);
```

Comment: Yes, I thought it's supposed by your code. Can you add a result of print_r($_POST['countries']); call to your start topic?